# Contour Integral of $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}\,dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Find the integral $$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}\,dz$$

I can see that there is a pole at $z = 0$. But I don't know how to solve that integral over that way.

Comment: Hint: use the power series for $\sin z.$

Comment: You can also just use Cauchy's integral formula,$$f'(a)=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}\,\mathrm dz$$(terms and conditions apply)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know

$$\sin z = z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - \dots$$

In fact, operations on Power/Laurent series end up being exactly what we expect in the naive fashion:

$$\frac{\sin z}{z^2} = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{z}{3!} + \frac{z^3}{5!} - \dots$$

So by the Residue Theorem: $$\oint_{S^2} \frac{\sin z}{z^2} dz = 2\pi i$$

Comment: [fyi](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)